# Colpitts oscillator with a series inductance π-network

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

In a Colpitts oscillator, the feedback occurs via a series inductance π-network. An, based on a common-emitter BJT amplifier, is shown in the circuit below.

[image]

Here below is a simplified version.

[image]

This circuit is equivalent to the following with voltages inside the circuits.

[image]

We will use Thevenin circuit to analyse C2 first.

[image]

$$
\frac{1} {R} + \frac{1} {1/(s C_2) + s L} = \frac{1} {R_{p_{2}}}
$$

$$
R_{p_2}
=
\frac{R\,\left(1+C_{2}\,L\,s^2\right)}{1+C_{2}\,R\,s+C_{2}\,L\,s^2}
$$

$$
I_2(s)
=
\frac{V_0} {s} 
\frac{R_{p_2}} {\bigl(R_{p_2} + 1 / (s C_1) \bigl)}
\frac{1} {1/(s C_2) + s L}
$$

$$
I_2(s)
=
\frac{C_{1}\,C_{2}\,R\,V_{0}\,s}{1+C_{2}\,R\,s+C_{1}\,R\,s+C_{2}\,L\,s^2+C_{1}\,C_{2}\,L\,R\,s^3}
$$

Similarly, we will use Thevenin circuit to analyse C1.

[image]

$$
\frac{1} {R} + \frac{1} {1/(s C_2) + s L} = \frac{1} {R_{p_{2}}}
$$

$$
R_{p_2}
=
\frac{R\,\left(1+C_{2}\,L\,s^2\right)}{1+C_{2}\,R\,s+C_{2}\,L\,s^2}
$$

$$
I_2(s)
=
\frac{V_0} {s} 
\frac{R_{p_2}} {\bigl(R_{p_2} + 1 / (s C_1) \bigl)}
\frac{1} {1/(s C_2) + s L}
$$

$$
I_2(s)
=
\frac{C_{1}\,C_{2}\,R\,V_{0}\,s}{1+C_{2}\,R\,s+C_{1}\,R\,s+C_{2}\,L\,s^2+C_{1}\,C_{2}\,L\,R\,s^3}
$$

According to Thevenin equivalent circuit analysis, we know that

$$
I_1(s) + I_2(s) = g_m V_{\pi}
$$

$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{C_{2}\,\left(V_{\pi }+C_{1}\,R\,V_{\pi }\,s+C_{1}\,R\,V_{0}\,s\right)}{1+C_{2}\,R\,s+C_{1}\,R\,s+C_{2}\,L\,s^2+C_{1}\,C_{2}\,L\,R\,s^3}
=
g_m V_{\pi}
$$

However, the book gave me a total different answer.

Here was what the book said. The book *An Introduction to Radio Frequency Engineering* is written by Christopher Coleman.

This is the book link
[Click here for book info](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/an-introduction-to-radio-frequency-engineering/oscillators-and-phase-locked-loops/E3EFC6E1808D893163A9DB676D26980B)

$$
s C_2 + g_m + (\frac{1} {R} + s C_1) (1 + s^2 C_2 L) = 0
$$

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: The voltage across capacitors cannot be replaced with independent sources. Why did you do that?

Comment: @sarthak Laplace Transform Analysis

Comment: @TimWilliams How do you get the formula of the book? And how do you analyse the circuit?

Comment: Writing equations and solving. I should not transforming schematic.

Comment: @Antonio51 What do you mean? Anything wrong with my way of analysing?

Comment: No. Nothing "wrong". I do it now with "software tools".

Comment: @Antonio51 What software did you use for this kind of Analysis?

Comment: I use microcap v12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm for simulating first if circuit is working ... and then for mathematical background, Maple (sometimes with Syrup extension). I tried your circuit (with some additions for bias), no success until now (does not oscillate).

Comment: @kile Your circuit transformation from figure 2 to figure 3 is incorrect, they are not equivalent circuits. You should use the Laplace transform for the original circuit. Figure 3 assumes independent step input of Vo and Vpi which does not make any sense for the original circuit. Further, the derivation is already provided in the book, so what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: @sarthak I don't know how the author get  the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched for a working circuit ...
Here are the schematic and behavior.

Starting the oscillator ... (weird !)

[image]

Steady state oscillator ... Don't know if it stops after some time (simulation longgg).

[image]

Here is a Maple sheet for calculating ... frequency and plot of the collector voltage.

[image]

[image]

Zeroes and poles are listed.
The oscillator frequency oscillation is confirmed by microcap v12 simulation.